# Java/MySQL - Erro na query

Tags: java, mysql, servlet

Olá, Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação simples de cadastro no banco com Java e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Count Zero', 234, 'Gibson, W', 'Aleph' )' at line 1
```

LivroDAO:

```
public void abrirConexao() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try {
        con = Conexao.getConnection();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void adicionar(Livro livro) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    abrirConexao();
    //Livro li = (Livro) livro;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO livros");
        sql.append("(titulo, paginas, autor, editora) ");
        sql.append("values ");
        sql.append("(?, ?, ?, ?)");

        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        System.out.println(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, livro.getTitulo());
        //System.out.println(livro.getTitulo());
        stmt.setInt(2, livro.getPaginas());
        //System.out.println(livro.getPaginas());
        stmt.setString(3, livro.getAutor());
        stmt.setString(4, livro.getEditora());

        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
public Servlet() {
    super();

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Livro li = new Livro(request.getParameter("titulo")
                            ,new Integer(request.getParameter("paginas"))
                            ,request.getParameter("autor")
                            ,request.getParameter("editora"));
        System.out.print(li.toString());
        LivroDAO dao = new LivroDAO();
        dao.adicionar(li);
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("titulo"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("paginas"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("autor"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("editora"));

        request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erro");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Pelo que eu entendi, o erro está na query que eu crio na String SQL, porém não consigo identificar o que está de errado. Já testei a mesma dentro do banco, já coloquei toda a query sem StringBuffer, coloquei/tirei os parênteses depois de values.

Comment: O seu banco está usando um separador de `String` como `'`?

Comment: Não sei, como faço para saber?

Comment: Seria a string `"INSERT INTO Livros"` que está faltando um espaço após o `"Livros"`?

Comment: Depois que voce falou eu testei só por garantia, mas também não era. Antes de usar o String Builder eu estava usando uma String normal e apontava o mesmo erro

Comment: O nome da sua tabela é mesmo Livros?

Comment: Sim, e só pra constar, tanto no banco quanto no código é "livros" tudo minusculo

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL e do driver que você está utilizando?

Comment: MySQL Workbech 6.3, driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Mas e a versão do MySQL Server e a versão do Driver do MySQL?

Comment: Me perdoe a falta de conhecimento, mas como faço pra conferir as versões? Se estiver se referindo ao arquivo jar do mysql, seria o `mysql-connector-java-5.1.45`

Comment: Use `SELECT VERSION();` ou vá na pasta de instalação do MySQL server, o nome dela contém a versão.

Comment: ok, a versão do MySQL Server é `5.7.20`

Comment: Tente usar um *driver* mais recente, como o 6.0.6. Se você não usa um gerenciador de dependências, baixe ele [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.6).

Comment: Ok, amanhã a noite testarei e farei um update aqui

Comment: Não sei que bruxaria você fez, mas é isso mesmo Felipe. Atualizei o driver e foi de primeira, muito obrigado amigo, tirou até um peso de mim porquê estava há mais de uma semana sem produzir nada hahaha